# the impact of stationarity on forecasting possibilities

Tags: time-series, noise

I am looking to forecast a series, which is non-stationary.
I have been taught from university to make the series stationary (by for example differencing).

Then i think about a (weak) stationary processes, which has constant mean and the correlation coefficient between points in time is constant (lets say a white noise process).

In what way would it help to make a process (weak) stationary when i want to predict the process (a white noise process, for example, is unpredictable)?